# IF statement to reference cell on another worksheet

Tags: excel, formula

I have an excel spreadsheet with numerous worksheets. I have a cell in Worksheet 1 that is a drop down list.

This cell is then populated on worksheet 2 C7 using a cell reference (i.e. ='Worksheet 1'!J30)

I want another cell on worksheet 2 that says if C7="Other" to then get the cell reference from 'Worksheet 1'!K30

Is this possible? Or is there a better way. It is a drop down list of suppliers.

Comment: The `IF` function should work across worksheets within the same workbook AFAIK.  So yes, what you are describing should work.

Comment: I've tried everything and it doesn't work.

Comment: `it doesn't work` doesn't help us to give you any help.  Show some data please.

Comment: It's not list data. It's using excel as a form. Information in worksheet 1 is used to populate information on Worksheet 2. On Worksheet 2, I need a formula to say if cell equals "Other" to get another cell from Worksheet 1.

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work by using "EXACT" in the formula.

Answer (score -1):

Are you writing IF statement in VBA?

Comment: No. Just a formula.